# Unable to launch a Dataflow template using API client library (Java) as I am getting Invalid argument exception

Tags: java, google-api, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

The interesting fact is that I am able to launch the Dataflow template from cloud shell, as well as from Google OAuth2 playground console. When I try to launch it using the API client library with the same set of details, I am getting 400 Bad request error.

URL Used:

```
GenericUrl URL = new GenericUrl("https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/servicetesting-g-1575763471750/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_Cloud_PubSub");
```

POST Body content:

```
{
  "jobName":"st-txt-to-pubsub",
  "parameters":
  {
    "inputFilePattern":"gs://soa_global_storage/input/my_input.txt",
    "outputTopic":"projects/servicetesting-g-1575763471750/topics/Input_Topic_PUB"
  },
        "environment": { "zone": "us-central1" }
 }
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The template parameters are invalid.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The template parameters are invalid.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to use the same exact job and environment parameters. For example, `us-central1` is a region but not a valid zone ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#locations)). Insted, use `us-central1-a` (or `b`, `c`, `f`)

Comment: @GuillemXercavins - No luck :(

Comment: I know it looks silly but sometimes **Json** can be a bit picky on quotes. Once I ran into this issue simply because I had **double quotes** instead of **simple quotes**. Try changing all your quotes to **simple quotes** and remind to set your **zone** like Guillem mentioned. If this doesn't work, please share link to the sample code you are using to make the call as well as the template so I can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: If this solved your issue, please confirm and I will post this comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on your template metadata, be sure the field name is the same you call in the POST body. Check also if the parameters pass on the regex test.

As others have said, you also have to correct your zone to `us-central1-a`, or you can leave it blank.

Ex. of metadata that would fit your content:

```html
    {
  "description": "enter your description",
  "name": "template_name",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "inputFilePattern",
      "helpText": "Bucket URI",
      "regexes":["^gs://.*"],
      "label": "input file pattern"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputTopic",
      "helpText": "lorem ipsum",
      "label": "Topic on Pub/sub",
    }
  ]
}
```

Worth to mention that you should try the template with the parameters in the console. If doesn't work there, it won't work anywhere.